# Is present continuous ok with "this is the last time"

Tags: present-tense

Is it possible to say or write

> this is the last time I am bothering you with that I won't do it again

or is it better to write or say

> this is the last time I have bothered you with that

I think the first one with present continuous is not possible because using present continuous means that the action is not finished. I can't use the last time if the action is not finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is often called a **statement of fact** using will (It is not a future):

**This is the last time I will bother you and won't do it again.**

**This is the last time I'll do your homework for you.**

Alternatively,  you can use going to express you intention not to bother the person:

**This is the last time I'm going to bother you.**

Comment: But could I say   " This is the last time i'll do your homework" even if I was  doing the homework (may be for the last time)at the time of speaking

Comment: @user5577 Yes, that is exactly when you would say it. Because you are actually doing it. So, it refers to the present. Another example of this usage is:Boys will be boys. A statement of fact.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: use the word 'will':

> this will be the last time I bother you
>
> this is the last time I will bother you

Reviewing the sentences you mentioned:

> this is the last time I am bothering you

It's an unusual expression, emphasizing that the bothering is occurring at that very moment, and is continuing.

If the action were a different one, then the grammatical form of the sentence could make sense: "this is the last time I am going out with you!".

> this is the last time I have bothered you

Not a good choice because of mixing-and-matching the verb tenses. "have bothered" is present perfect. "this is" is present tense.